# Ubuntu deletes text file on pressing Enter key in filemanagers

Tags: 16.04, files, delete, filemanager

Recently I have a strange behavior with .txt and .srt extensions in my filesystem. When I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when file selected with intent to open the file, in both Nemo or Nautilus filemanager, file gets deleted. It is not found in trash, real `rm` delete.

Does anyone have an idea what have I done? How can I revert this behavior?

Comment: Seems like you mapped a command to the enter key.  You'll have to find and delete it (using the mouse).  I use KDE, so not sure where to look on GNOME.  Also seems like the delete warning dialog has been disabled.  You might want to reenable it.

Comment: Thanks, it was a different situation, I had to reinstall gedit.

Comment: How did gedit make nautilus delete files?

Comment: I don't know, but my delete warning dialog was turned on with other files, so thanks for tip, that how I assumed problem might be with executing the file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that my .txt and .srt files were linked to gedit on this PC, when I assigned different viewer, files were not deleted. I assigned gedit again to this extension and files were being deleted again. Strange. After removing and reinstalling of gedit, problem disappeared. I don't know whether gedit was corrupted, or it is a bug but I have to move on at this moment, for me problem is solved for now, hope this helps someone with the same problem.